# constrOptim function: Optimize R code

Tags: r, optimization

I am trying to solve an optimization problem.

Below is the mathematical explanation of the problem and the code I used:

F = {f_1, f_2, ... f_n}

S = {s_1, s_2, ....s_m}

Here m is always greater than n, and sum(S) is always greater than sum(F)

if ST = transpose(S)

Find a matrix P (n x m) = {p_ij}, such that: P %* % ST = F, where %* % is matrix multiplication, with respect to following constraints:

1. p_ij>= 0, for all i and j
2. sum (p_ij) <=1 when i varies from 1 to n.

Since the exact solution may not exist, I am trying to minimize Error by minimizing [ P %* % ST - F ].[ P %* % ST - F ], where . is the dot product

So the problem is that of constrained optimization where I use the following code.

```
F = c(10,10,5)
S = c(8,8,9,8,4)

loss_fun <- function(P){
    T = matrix(S*P, nrow = n,ncol = m, byrow=T)
    F2 = rowSums(T) # Predicted values of F
    E = F - F2  # Error
    return(sum(E*E))    
}

n = length(F)
m = length(S)
P_init = c(rep(0.0001,n*m)) #Initial solution (theta)

# Creating constraint matrix
ui_1 = matrix(0,ncol = n*m, nrow= m) 
for (i in 1:m){
    for (j in 1:(n*m)) {
        if (i%%m==j%%m) ui_1[i,j] = -1
    }
}
ui_2 = diag(1,ncol = n*m, nrow = m*n)
my_ui <- rbind(ui_1,ui_2)

# Creating constraint vector
my_ci = c(rep(-1,m),rep(0,n*m))

z = constrOptim(P_init,loss_fun,NULL,ui=my_ui, ci=my_ci)

#result
P_final = matrix(z$par,nrow=n,byrow=T)

#verification of result
T = t(S*t(P_final)) #proportion matrix * S, transpose to ensure multiplication is by row.
F2 = rowSums(T) # Predicted values of F
E = F - F2  # Error
sum(E*E)
```

The above code works fine and runs in less than 0.5 seconds on my machine which has i5 CPU, 4 cores, 8 GB RAM, 64 bit windows 7, and 64 bit R 3.1.1.

However when I used F and S as in my real problem it ran for around 15 hours without producing any output. F has 39 elements, S has 196.

```
F = c(212,359,186,396,460,449,206,180,383,264,294,179,256,294,173,415,363,323,389,219,298,338,287,434,195,450,120,460,164,395,198,108,72,345,54,450,420,488,262)
S = c(233.81,0,1.13,59.68,0,768.18,12.33,147.56,115.2,537.32,0,144.35,93.63,13.43,48.58,60,78.26,1280,369.62,8.11,0,342.96,452.99,521.72,4995.58,0,0,10.59,8.1,38.89,161.67,186.14,0,83.22,13.89,37.35,2370,0,0,8.61,4.95,6.31,0,1.53,3600,0,12.48,444.26,0,8490,615.25,27.11,402.95,393.46,1.26,0,44.36,728.85,37.61,159.06,103.63,145.38,0.51,0,0,18.6,3.24,44.5,17.46,210,128.03,19.48,340.79,54.79,54.42,48.48,0,44.76,0,0,0,43.19,102.03,0,0,470,0,101,0,9060,6.09,8.33,49.09,0,19.72,170,57.54,128.78,636.01,10.93,38.79,0,0,49.65,173.58,101.96,21.84,2.55,14.55,770,7419.13,216.21,238.15,582.95,57.93,26.97,71.88,4.63,0,31,103.37,570.58,45.79,540,348.9,151.82,207.41,29.56,51.73,92.25,0,0,51.39,25.14,0,0,95.21,298.94,5.77,154.29,280,1666.59,40.19,0,9.37,119.76,0,0,9.17,28.19,67.5,129.62,85.41,24.59,3607.98,0,130.28,99.57,0,0,0,36.23,1140,328.87,0,0,0,40,22.77,0,2.08,0,0,0,14.66,0,102.86,50.06,13.22,62.25,1410,860,930,646.15,0,0,0,0,890,0,0,12.61,86.4,95.35,19.31,87.74
)
```

The `rbind` itself takes 3 to 4 seconds but the real problem is time taken by `constrOptim`.

Comment: You may want to provide gradients.

Comment: Yeah, trying to calculate the same. Seems difficult mathematics to me

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen, as per your suggestion, i have tried to create a gradient and asked whether my gradient is correct or not here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2018085/compute-derivative-with-respect-to-a-matrix. Would it be possible for you to answer it there?

Comment: This model should solve easily in less than a few seconds using a good solver. If you use a QP solver you don't need to provide gradients. If you write a fit as a linear constraint `sum(j, p(i,j)*s(j)) = f(i) + e(i)` where `e` is variable indicating the residual, you can just minimize `sum(i, sqr(e(i))`. A good solver like Cplex should solve this in about 0.1 seconds.

Comment: Thank for the info, however I do not have access to anything other than R.    Also, I do not fully understand the syntax of constraint you have written, could you kindly elaborate a bit.

Comment: I solved: `min sum(i,sqr(e(i))` subject to `sum(j, p(i,j)*x(j)) = f(i)+e(i)`, `p(i,j)>=0` and `sum(i, p(i,j))<=1`. Here `e(i)` are additional decision variables (so I made the problem larger), but this makes the objective easier (the model is less nonlinear). I can solve this in 0.15 seconds with Cplex and 1.5 seconds with IPOPT for your large dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your constraint is simple, you can avoid big-matrix calculations in the constraint part when you use some packages that can take function as a constraint argument, such as `alabama`.

```
loss_fun <- function(P){
  T = matrix(S*P, nrow = n,ncol = m, byrow=T)
  F2 = rowSums(T) # Predicted values of F
  E = F - F2  # Error
  return(sum(E*E))    
}

n = length(F)
m = length(S)
P_init = c(rep(0.0001, n*m)) #Initial solution (theta)

# Creating inequality constraint function (this is much faster than my_ui %*% P - my_ci)
hin <- function(P){
  P_mat <- matrix(P, nrow = m)
  c(rowSums(P_mat) * -1 +1, P)
}

library(alabama)
aug_res <- auglag(P_init, loss_fun, hin = hin, control.outer = list(kkt2.check = FALSE))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, I will test this against my code on smaller size problems first and let you know

Comment: thanks @cuttlefish44, On testing on smaller sized problems, your code was more than 10 time faster. So I ran your answer on my real problem and it took 6813 seconds (around 2 hours). I read (and as @ErwinKalvelagen) told, putting a  gradient could be much faster specially for higher dimensional problems, I created the gradient as: `gr <- function(P){
P_mat = matrix(P,nrow=n,byrow=T);
gr = -2 * ((F - P_mat %*% S)) %*% t(S)
}`. However when I run `auglag` with gradient, results are different. I am sure I am doing some mistake in structuring the gradient function

Comment: I need to add one more constraint, Some of the p_ij has to be 0. I tried to implement that but I get an error. Could you help me with that as well.  This is how I have written equality constraint - `heq <- function(P) {
  P[which(P==0)]
}`

Comment: I am getting an error after 8th iteration:
`Error in colSums(lam[-inactive] * ij) : 
  'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions`

Also, at 8th iteration, I can see the values I wanted as 0 are more than 0.

Comment: @Gaurav Singhal; Sorry, I wish I could help you out, but I can't. Some of p_ij having 0 is expressed by `sum(P == 0) > 0`. But it looks problem of discrete value and I don't know a package treating such problem with continuous value.  When I use `prod(P) == 0`, `prod(P)` approximates 0 but all elements of P are `> 0`.

Comment: Thanks, ... I will anyway try sum(P==0) though to see what happens.